# Grab the contents of <TD> and multiply/divide it accordingly using jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm in the process of developing an easy-to-use comparison table for users who are looking to upgrade their processor, using the Intel GM965 chipset. It can be found here - http://dylricho.com/archive/gm965/

I was actually making it for myself since I'm going to go from an M 575 to a T9500 soon, but I thought I might as well upload it for others to use.

Regardless, I've been trying to find out a simple way to use jQuery/JavaScript to multiply or divide a number (found in a table cell element) by 1000. As an example, this would be used if the user wanted to convert gigahertz into megahertz so comparing multiple CPUs was easier.

As you can see from the link above, I have one way working, although I'm having to list each processor entry manually in the JS file. I was hoping there was a simple way to grab each value of the **Clock Frequency** column and multiply or divide in one click of the red units in the table headers.

In my mind, I had a code like this which looks like it should work, but it doesn't:

```
$('.clock').text() / 1000; // To get back to GHz from MHz
```

The necessary JS files are listed below for convenience:

- dylricho.com/archive/gm965/changeTitlesOnLoad.js
- dylricho.com/archive/gm965/convertClockToMHz.js
- dylricho.com/archive/gm965/convertClockToGHz.js

In the *convertClockToMHz.js* file, you can see that I'm currently listing each processor entry manually.

I know I could just continue to do it all manually, but the list is going to be rather large, and it'd be much better if it was with one line of code.

Thank you,
Dylan.

Comment: have divs that are pre-calculated and hide/show the ones that aren't selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.clock').text() / 1000;` does not do anything since you are not passing any argument to `text()` to update the DOM.

Try this:

```
$('.clock').text(function(index, oldText){    
     return parseFloat( oldText / 1000, 2);    
});
```

Comment: I just searched around Stack Overflow, and found I could use :contains to determine a clock frequency. I don't mind listing frequencies once, just not *every* CPU. And :contains seems to work. Thank you for that method, also. :)

Comment: don't see how you would use `:contains` for this situation

Comment: I'll upload and you can check it out. There you go. :)

Comment: that is sure a lot of redundant manual coding using `contains`

Comment: Regardless, it still beats listing 100 processors. If need be, I will try a different method in the future. :)

Comment: i think you are grossly over complicating it

Comment: That's usually me for you. It should all work now. Not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

A different way is to pre-calculate all values in the table and hide show the ones that are selected

```
<table>
    <td>
        <div class="field degrees faren">32</div>
        <div class="field degrees celci">0</div>
    </td>
</table>
```

Then something like

```
$(".field.degrees").hide('fast')
$(".field.degrees.celci").show('fast')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#clock-2 a").click( function() {
     $(".clock").each( function() {
         var s = parseFloat($(this).text(), 10);
         var num = s/1000;
         $(this).html(num);
      });
});
```

Comment: `parseInt` will remove decimals and therefore throw off calculations

Comment: @charlietfl thats right :D and why you in your answer used radix equal to 2. Its for binary numbers.